# change variable value based on radio button selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to calculate final price based on radio button selection, but in my case it only showing first radio button value in page. when checked another, it doesnt change.

this is my code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <input name="gfee" type="hidden" id="gdfee" value="<?php echo $grow['fee'];?>">
                    <label>
                        <div id="rates">
                        <input type="radio" name="visaoption" id ="a" value="60" checked="checked">   Normal <span>- Processing within 3 days</span></label><br>

                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="visaoption" id="b" value="100"> Urgent <span>- Guaranteed processing in less than 1 hour (+50$)</span> </label><br>
                        </div>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var govfee = document.getElementById('gdfee').value;
                        var afee = document.querySelector('input[name="visaoption"]:checked').value
                        var totalfee = parseFloat(govfee) + parseFloat(afee);
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = govfee;
                        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = afee;
                        document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = totalfee;

                    }
                    );

                    </script>                       
                    <p id="demo"></p>   
                    <p id="demo2"></p>
                    <p id="demo3"></p>                          
                 </div>
            </div>
```

and also how can we pass 'var totalfee' to data-amount="" in below script that is on same page inside same form.

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="secret-key"
    data-amount="Total Fee"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Debit/Credit Card"
    data-name="Turkey Services"
    data-description="Purchase Description"
    data-image="logo url"
    data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
    data-prefill.email="test@test.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
>
</script>
```

Comment: You're not listening for any radio button change event...?

Comment: @Jeto : Sir, Can you help me out with a working code, how can i apply on change event here. not able to solve.

Comment: Learn about [listening to DOM events in jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/).